# Mac terminal unix questions. Trying to install showoff.io

Tags: mac-osx, shell, ruby, path, rubygems

I installed the gem according to the instructions at [showoff.io](https://showoff.io/), but when I try to run

```
show 8888
```

it doesn't work and I get

```
-bash: show: command not found
```

In their [faq](https://showoff.io/support#faq), they mention running

```
gem contents showoff-io
```

if that happens, but I don't know how to read what I get:

```
Rakefile
Gemfile
lib/showoff/client.rb
lib/showoff/settings.rb
lib/showoff/api.rb
lib/showoff/helpers.rb
lib/showoff/version.rb
lib/showoff/setup.rb
lib/showoff/session.rb
lib/showoff.rb
bin/show
```

They say this:

> This will list all of the files in the showoff-io gem. Look for the bin/show script. Either add that folder to your $PATH, or symlink the script into a location already on your $PATH. For example:

```
sudo ln -s /var/ruby/gems/.../bin/show /usr/local/bin
```

But obviously copy&pasting that doesn't do anything because those are just example paths.

I'm sure this is very basic, but I'm a novice at this. What do I have to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed as your "normal" user account (didn't sudo), you most likely missed the warning message like this one:

```
WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 and
          /usr/bin aren't both writable.
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/jclark/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH,
          gem executables will not run.
```

Try this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin
show 3000
```

If that works, then simply do this to add it to your path every time you open a terminal.

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:~/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin" >> ~/.bash_profile
```